# Can i retrieve information from external website when i'm on an intranet using php function file_get_contents?

Tags: php, facebook, curl, httpwebrequest, file-get-contents

I'm trying to retrieve information of an external website from the intranet using file_get_contents and curl, but unfortunately i fail to get the data, i have asked the system administrator to give me access to that specific site which is facebook.com and when i put in the url directly inside the address bar i can open the webpage but now when i want to access it through my intranet it gives me an error

```
An error occured while fetching the URI. Please retry.
```

and my code is

> ```
>  $url = 'http://www.facebook.com';
>  //curl script to get content of given url
>  $ch = curl_init();
>  // set the target url
>  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
>  // request as if Firefox
>  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U;   Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.15) Gecko/20080623 Firefox/2.0.0.15") ); 
>  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
>  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
>  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
>  $result= curl_exec ($ch); 
>  curl_close ($ch);
> ```

and facebook has been blocked on our firewall but i thought since i can access directly from the browser the i should be able to access it, but it seems like the firewall is not seeing the request as being sent by me, is the request maybe been sent by the intranet ip address? is it even possible?

Comment: is the php script in a computer with access to facebook? the request is sent by the server parsing the php, not by the user navigating

Comment: i don't think the server have access to interact with the outsite world since its 4 the intranet, but i wasnt sure whether i was sending the request or the server was doing that..thanks for highlighting that, now i have to go fight with the system administrator.. :(

Answer (score 0):

> i have asked the system administrator to give me access to that specific site

"me" or "my script"?

> when i want to access it through my intranet

what does it mean - "through my intranet"?
aren't you already inside of intranet, even when "put in the url directly inside the address bar"?

Anyway, you still have to ask your system administrator, not folks on stackoverflow. We have no control of your intranet firewall

Comment: no  need to be so hard on me, i'm a programmer not a system administrator or network specialist so thats y it kind of confuses me what sent out requests